# What are these file types that Visual Studio is creating in a WinForms project folder?

Tags: c#, winforms

Today I just happened to have my windows explorer opened while working on a `Form` in a C# WinForms project opened in Visual Studio 2015; it was displaying the contents of the project's UI files.

At one point I noticed these odd files being created in the directory
[image]

What are they for?

After I noticed them I went to take a better picture than the one provided and went to sort the file name column, they then disappeared from the folder and I have not seen them since.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio does a lot behind the scenes when you're building or doing other things, including auto-generating weird looking temp files like these.

Looks like these are temp files that you aren't supposed to see.  But you had that path open in your windows explorer and it didn't refresh and clear them like it's supposed to.

Basically, don't worry about it.  Those files are always getting generated and deleted and you just don't notice.

Sorry I can't point you to a helpful resource, as I couldn't find anything about this on Google.

Comment: Just for interest's sake, I take it there is no way to tell what these specific files (not the files pictured, but files in the category of those pictured) are for? (ie what info does a`.xoo` file contain?)

Comment: The image I have in my head is of a programmer working on the new Visual Studio update, and he needs to write a temp file to your local drive, so he names it whatever and gives it an extension of whatever.  I assume nobody except for the VS dev team knows what those temp files are used for.  But I could be wrong!  

I couldn't find anything online about either of those file extensions.